# nested query doesnt work in SailsJs

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I would like to make a query for retrieve "All projects, that have a specific member".

Project.js:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
        type: "string"
    },

    topics: {
        collection: "topic",
        via: "projects"
    },

    profesor: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    creator: {
      type: 'string' 
    },

    members: {
        collection: "user",
      via: "projects"
    },

    content: {
        collection: "content",
        via: "projectData"
    }

  }
};
```

User.js:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    projects: {
      collection:"project",
      via: "members",
      dominant: true
    },

    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    mat: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },

    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
    },

    lastname: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
    },

    admin: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },


    encryptedPassword : {
        type: 'string'
    },

     toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      delete obj.encryptedPassword;
      delete obj.confirmation;
      delete obj._csrf;
      return obj;
    }

  },


  beforeValidate: function (values, next) {
    console.log(values);
    if (typeof values.admin !== 'undefined') {
      if (values.admin === 'unchecked') {
        values.admin = false;
      } else  if (values.admin[1] === 'on') {
        values.admin = true;
      }
    }
     next();
  },

  beforeCreate: function (values, next) {

    User.count().exec(function countCB(error, found) {
      if (found == 0) {
      values.admin = true;
      }
   });

    // This checks to make sure the password and password confirmation match before creating record
    if (!values.password || values.password != values.confirmation) {
      return next({err: ["Password doesn't match password confirmation."]});
    }

    require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, encryptedPassword) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      values.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
      // values.online= true;
      next();
    });
  }

};
```

and this is my query:

```
index: function(req,res){
        Project.find().populate('members', {name: 'Hugo'}).exec(function(err, prj){
                if (err) res.negotiate(err);
                console.log("funciona esto?");
                console.log(prj);


                res.view({
                project: prj
                });
        });
    },
```

Why doesnt work? It retrives all project, anybody can help me? I am not sure if waterline allows that.

Comment: Your query translates to find all the project and populate members wherever member's name is 'Hugo'. You should find all the projects of all members named 'Hugo' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the user, then populate the projects:

```
index: function(req,res){
        User
        .find({name: 'Hugo'})
        .populate('projects')
        .exec(function(err, user){
                if (err) res.negotiate(err);
                console.log("funciona esto?");
                console.log(user.projects);


                res.view({
                project: user.projects[0] // first project
                });
        });
    },
```